# How to use SQLite 3's vacuum command in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I cannot find any example on the net of how the SQLite 3 vacuum command is done on a database.

Answer (score 37):

Just open a connection and execute the VACUUM command;

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_FILE)
conn.execute("VACUUM")
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 11):

the other solutions didn't work for me
Error was `can't vacuum with transaction` or similar

here what worked for me:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db",isolation_level=None)
conn.execute("VACUUM")
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import sqlite3  

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")  
…  
conn.execute("VACUUM") 
…
```