# SQLite database file size didn't shrink after dropping huge table

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a table in my database file which turned out to be way too huge (increased my database file's size from 2 GB to around 50GB). I just dropped it but the file size didn't go down. Any way to get the db file back to normal? I'm using sqlite3 from Python.

Comment: See this [so question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712929/how-to-use-sqlite3s-vacuum-command-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: Can you bring the most relevant code to this answer. When the link goes dead the answer becomes useless and when I follow that link I have to dig through your repository to understand what I need to do. This Q/A pair is listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu/334916#334916). The question is not close-worthy so I rather salvage the answer.

Comment: @Mistalis The relevant code would be something like `conn.execute("VACUUM")`. However, the original (6-year-old) question is asking for a one-time solution, so likely the better approach is to call `vacuum` from the sqlite command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can activate [auto_vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) so you don't need to bother with running vacuum moving forward.